# Condition number of matrix algorithm

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

How can I find condition number for this matrix $$ \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
3& -1& 1\\
-1&2&3\\
1&3&3 \end{array} \right| $$
I just don't get algorithm for this kind of tasks. Can you explain it?

Comment: Is this a matrix ? or determinant

Comment: Cond(A)=$$||A||.||A^{-1}||$$